# onActivityResult not being called in custom Fragment or anywhere else attempted

Tags: android, android-fragments

There have been many successful answers to this question, but there's still something I'm not understanding or that I'm doing incorrectly. One answer is implementing `onActivityResult` in the host `Activity`, but I guess I don't know which one that is or I'm following it wrong.

And no, I'm not calling `getActivity.startActivityForResult()`, just `startActivityForResult()`.

Depending on a selection made in `FirstActivity`, one or more other selections are possible, created using `Fragments`. One `Fragment` is `ButtonFragment`, which when selected, starts `OptionsActivity`, like so:

```
public class ButtonFragment extends Fragment
{
  .....

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
  {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
    {
       if(requestCode == OPTIONS_REQUEST_CODE)
       {
          Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
          if (extras != null) {
             String selection = (String) extras.get("optionsSelection");
             data.setText(selection);
          }
       }
    }
  }

  private void openOptionsActivity()
  {
     Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), OptionsActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("optionsArray", options);
     startActivityForResult(intent, OPTIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
  }
}
```

This fragment is being added in `BaseActivity`:

```
public class BaseActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
  .....

    fm.beginTransaction().add(
            R.id.FragmentContainer, frag).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    fm.executePendingTransactions();

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
  {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     finish();
  }
}
```

Inside `OptionsActivity`:

```
public class OptionsActivity extends BaseSpinnerActivity
{
  .....

  private class OptionsAdapter extends BaseSpinnerAdapter
  {
    public OptionsAdapter(Context context, Object[] values)
    {
       super(context, values);
    }

    protected void fillRow(ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
       String option = options[position];

       if(option != null) {
          holder.text.setText(option);
       }
    }

    protected void onRowSelect(View v)
    {
       Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
       String optionSelection = (String)v.getTag();
       returnIntent.putExtra("optionSelected", optionSelection);
       setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
       finish();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
  {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    finish();
  }
}
```

The same thing is done inside `BaseSpinnerActivity`, which extends from `ListActivity`. (I know, should use `FragmentActivity`, but I haven't had a chance to convert it yet.)

None of these `onActivityResult()`'s are being called.

What am I missing or doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: in same Activity in which activity you are adding `ButtonFragment` override `onActivityResult` then this method call

Comment: That's what I thought too, but it's not stopping there either. See my added info above.

Comment: What do you mean 'this method call'?

Comment: you call `startActicityForResult()` from ButtonFragment so override its `onActivityResult`

Comment: Yes, I failed to include that code earlier. It's there now. It still doesn't stop.

Comment: if you are overriding FragmentActivity.onActivityResult make sure you call super implementation, then Fragment.onActivityResult will be called nicely

Comment: @pskink Near as I can tell, that's what I'm doing, but it's not working.

Comment: i cant tell you why its not working as i cannot see all of your code, but i am sure if you call startActivityForResult() in your Fragment and if you override that Fragment's onActivityResult (and only there) it **muust** work

Comment: That's not what others have said: like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment/#24303360)